# Upload certificate from azure rest api failing

Tags: python, azure, rest, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

Problem statement:

Renew the certificate in the apps registered under Azure AD.

Question:

I was facing an issue while sending a PATCH from the [MS Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) > applications - PATCH update application properties.

The issue is whenever I try to change the KeyCredentials and upload it fails with **key value cannot be null or empty**. Now, when I checked other certificates from the GET retrieve application property details, they were null. I can't understand what is this key value as I tried to read my certificate locally using OpenSSL and can't find any value as such.

Can anyone help me in the RestAPI or if there is any SDK that can help in uploading the certificate.

Regards

Comment: hello @Ayush Ujjwal, The key is the decrypted raw data of the certificate .So, you can use powershell to get the certificate and convert the rawdata to a base64 string .

Comment: But when I upload the certificate through the portal and do a get property request it shows null. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: [graph call without select](https://i.imgur.com/UnupV4T.png) & [graph call with select](https://i.imgur.com/YKIcUb6.png) you can refer these two images

Comment: Thanks @AnsumanBal-MT. I get it now. But let's suppose I want the complete fields and key also, I will have to provide all the fields in select= ... Is there any alternate way to handle this?

Comment: "Can you open the .cer file in a wordpad and let me know if it has ----begin certificate ------ and ----end certificate ---- or its unreadable ?" > yeah that's working now. THanks a lot for that.

Comment: Yeah, I can. But is there any way to upload the file instead of reading and making a patch request for the data?

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks : )

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue is whenever I try to change the KeyCredentials and upload it
fails with key value cannot be null or empty.**

> Ans: The Key Credential requires a value to be uploaded in key ,
> otherwise it will fail.

**Now, when I checked other certificates from the GET retrieve
application property details, they were null.**

> Ans:  It by default shows the secure string values as null when you do
> a select then only you can find out the secure string values.
> [image]

**I can't understand what is this key value as I tried to read my certificate locally using OpenSSL and can't find any value as such.**

> Ans: When you open the .cer file in wordpad it will show you something
> like :
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> <<sensitive_values>>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```
>
> Basically the sensitive value can be used for the value of key .

**But let's suppose I want the complete fields and key also, I will have to provide all the fields in select= ... Is there any alternate way to handle this?**

> Ans: There is no other way to get the values , except for selecting
> all the required fields you need.

**is there any way to upload the file instead of reading and making a patch request for the data?**

> Ans: Unfortunately No, As of now there is no direct way to upload a
> cert file instead of reading it and then uploading it.